# DB Query profiling in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, profiling, pg-promise

I am building a json API using `express` (well,  maybe will move to `koa`). I store my data in PostgreSQL database, and i use `pg-promise` to fetch data from it (`async/await` via babel).

I am totally new to node.js and i can't find any information about performance measurement in that environment.

To be specific:

```
module.exports.get_hierarchy = async function () {
    const rows = await postgres.any('SELECT id, parent, title, permission FROM heading');

    var result = [];
    // some black magic goes here...

    return result;
}
```

I want to know (programmatically *if possible*) how much time `SELECT` consumes. (Not the time promise lives from constructing to resolving, which can be achieved by taking two timestamps, but actual time consumed by the DB server to process query).

Can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: What you are looking for in PostgreSQL is called [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-explain.html) that you need to execute directly, best is via `pgAdmin` UI ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned it yourself, there are two ways to profile the execution time in your case:

- the time from you calling a method of `pg-promise` to getting the result back
- the time it takes to execute the query by the server

The first one is the easiest to do by using method [result](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#result), which resolves with `Result` object that has property `duration`.

And the second one requires direct execution of [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-explain.html), typically via the `pgAdmin` tool that comes with every PostgreSQL installation, or you can use psql terminal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to `result` method. How could i miss it? The downside is incompatibility with methods like `one` and `oneOrNone`, but it's bearable. Also `duration` property seems to be undocumented (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Query#result-object); i hope it isn't going to dissapear in future releases:)

Comment: Hey, and thank you for bringing such a great library to mankind:)

Comment: Property `duration` is documented in the [API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.result): `resolves with the original Result object, extended with property duration - query duration in milliseconds.` ;) And no, I'm not removing it in the future releases ;)